# Magento 1.7.0.2 refund doesn't sync with PayPal

Tags: magento, paypal, nvp

I hope you can help me.
I issued a full refund to a customer who paid through paypal.
Magento (v.1.7.0.2) has processed the refund correctly but hasn't synchronized with PayPal i.e. the refund has not been sent to the customer for real.

The PayPal customer service told me to read this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

But...what should I do? I just followed Magento and PayPal instructions in order to establish the connetction between the two (and PayPal confirms it's works).

The problem arose yesterday after I changed the API keys because of a change of PayPal account, it worked perfectly before that change. What can you suggest me to check / modify?

Thanks,
Giovanni

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you are using Paypal standard, Magento can't refund "online" (for real). This is not implemented. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30375154/2980105

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if your new account has the privileges of refunding.