# Magento - Online refund with PayPal

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Currently we have a Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 with installed PayPal Website Payments Standard option enabled. However when I want to do an online refund it doesn't show an 'Refund' button but only 'Offline refund'.

Is it actually possible to create an online refund with PayPal Standard?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with Paypal standard, you must overload the paypal standard model to implement the `refund` method, or you can install a module.

Comment: Can you suggest a module name?

Comment: Yep, the [luigifab/paypalrefund](https://redmine.luigifab.info/projects/magento/wiki/Paypalrefund-FR) module.

Answer (score 0):

As luigifab said, that functionality isn't part of the Paypal module - I've implemented a small add-on for it that can be seen here:

https://gist.github.com/bubach/ed86611c634b401e5d66392cf32c2f6e

The most important part being this class:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Paypal extends Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard
{

    protected $_canRefund               = true;
    protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial = true;
    protected $_canVoid                 = true;

    /**
     * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/
     */
    public function tryRefund(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
    {
        $transactionId = $payment->getLastTransId();

        if ($transactionId) {
            $order          = $payment->getOrder();
            $storeId        = $order->getStoreId();
            $refundType     = "Partial";
            $invoiceFee = $payment->getMethodInstance()->getInfoInstance()->getAdditionalInformation('invoice_fee');
            $remaining  = $order->getTotalInvoiced() - ($order->getTotalOfflineRefunded() + $order->getTotalOnlineRefunded()) - $invoiceFee;

            if (abs($remaining - $amount) < 0.00001) {
                $refundType = "Full";
            }

            $currencyCode   = $order->getBaseCurrencyCode();
            $invoiceId      = $order->getIncrementId();

            $params = array(
                "METHOD"        => "RefundTransaction",
                "VERSION"       => "72.0",
                "TRANSACTIONID" => $transactionId,
                "INVOICEID"     => $invoiceId,
                "REFUNDTYPE"    => $refundType,
                "AMT"           => $amount,
                "CURRENCYCODE"  => $currencyCode,
                "USER"          => Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/wpp/api_username', $storeId),
                "PWD"           => Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/wpp/api_password', $storeId),
                "SIGNATURE"     => Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/wpp/api_signature', $storeId)
            );

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($params));

            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                curl_close($ch);
                throw new Mage_Core_Exception('Impossible to issue a refund transaction because of cURL error.');
            } else  {
                curl_close($ch);

                $responseArray = array();
                parse_str($response, $responseArray); // Break the NVP string to an array

                if ($responseArray['ACK'] == "Success") {
                    return array(0, "Paypal refunded successfully");
                } else {
                    return array(-1, "Paypal refund failed!");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Impossible to issue a refund transaction because the capture transaction does not exist.'));
        }
    }
}
```